# Bootstrap column layout breaks on resize if resized back to the same size as on page load

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-multicolumn-layout

If I load my page everything is fine.
`<div class="sidebar">` uses exactly 320px whereas the `<div class="col">` uses the remaining space on the left. Both divs are in one row (side-by-side).

If I enlarge the browser window, everything is still fine (divs are side-by-side).

If I make the browser window smaller now (to the original size, when page was loaded), the layout breaks instantly (`<div class="sidebar">` is **below** `<div class="col">` now).

If I now reload the browser window, everything works fine again.

It seems like the left `<div class="col">` is not re-rendered quickly enough. And therefore when reduce the window size, the sidebar put below `<div class="col">`.

Is there another way to make such a layout: one div using fixed width for the sidebar and another div using flexible width (space left in the row next to the sidebar).

I am using the following markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar {
    width: 320px;
    padding: 10px 10px 0;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
}
```

Screenshot when page loaded (browser window = 1095px):
[image: image with sidebar]

Screenshot after enlarge and reduce the size of the browser window (to the original size when page was loaded (browser window = 1095px)!):
[image: image without sidebar]

Live example: https://www.lotsearch.net/artist/pablo-picasso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `calc`

```
.sidebar {
  width: 320px;
}
.col {
  width: calc(100% - 320px);
}
```

`sidebar` will cover 320px width and `col` will cover all remaining space.

Comment: I feel so dumb! Of course! Couldn't believe that I could not figured it out by myself! Thank you!
I fiddled a bit more with my code and it seems to work too when I set the width of `<div class="col">` to `1px`. The actual width of the div is not 1px but streched to the remaining space (without breaking the layout). I guess this is due flex box behavior...